# Передача данных между двумя телефонами под управлением Android

Tags: android

Стоит следующая задача, есть два телефона под управлением Android, на которых установлено одинаковое приложение. Как пользователю первого телефона передать пользователю второго телефона (скажем через whatsapp или telegram) какой то набор данных?
Понимаю что вопрос очень общий, но как его сформировать для того же Google я что то не представляю :(

PS
Ближайший аналог это наверное это передача контакта c первого телефона на второй с помощью какого то внешнего мессенджера.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, чем не подходит wi-fi, bluetooth?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich ну потому что мне нужен универсальный способ передачи данных, даже если второй телефон находится у другого человека, который в свою очередь находится где то далеко от меня но при этом имеет доступ в интернет

Comment: По почте отправить не вариант?

Comment: @woesss боюсь что нет

Comment: @plesser может быть вы интересуетесь шарингом? https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: @СтаниславГрот я думал об этом направлении, но тогда у меня возникает вопрос. Допустим я упаковываю бинарно свои данные и отправляю. Как на втором телефоне мне попытке открыть этот файл телефон поймет что нужно открыть именно мое приложение? Ведь когда я пересылаю таким образом контакт он как то понимает это и предлагает мне их импортировать...

Comment: Использовать свой сервер как посредника

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Я очень надеюсь обойтись пока без него :)

Comment: Использовать [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database/) как посредника.

Comment: Или [onesignal](https://onesignal.com/) сделать все через пуши

Comment: а как это реализовано при передаче того же контакта между телефонами?